# Can there be an error in data that causes a graph to give a warning?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, warnings

When I use the graph api to get public data from pages, I get for some pages a warning and other pages work fine. 
The warning is: `file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/318993554879922) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in ....`

When I look at the data of this company in the graph tool on Facebook, I can see everything I need. Everything look fine
How can I prevent this (or better: what advice can I give to the page owbers whose data I want to show on my website to change)?

I used to think that it was a setting in the profile picture because all pages that went wrong had a "custom" setting. That setting could not be changed. But I asked a page owner to upload a new picture and the problem stayed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the request is unsupported.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

So the API will return an HTTP 400 response to you.

It's either this object doesn't exist, was deleted or is a bug.

Comment: I think the other reason can be response time out. @phwd can it?

Comment: Maybe, the timeouts, are normally of message type "An unknown error has occured" but it could be a timeout.

Comment: The object exists because I see all data with the graph tool, I have seen the page live (not deleted and not unpublished) I actually went to see the owner of the data on his computer too and can't see anything strange.

Comment: And not a time out, get it immediately. One person who manages two pages can have one ok and the other not ok. Always the same, not random. So my guess is it's in the data...